# Angular 2 Multiple declaration error

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have three features module (including shared) in my application

```
1) CustomerModule
2) SiteModule
3) SharedModule
```

Both `Customer` and `Site` `module` import `shared` `module` and `Site module` eagerly load at `application` startup while the `customer module` configured to be `lazy load`.

Here my code looks like

**app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/sites',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'customers',
        loadChildren: 'app/customers/customers.module'
    },
]

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   imports:[routing, SiteModule],
   declarations:[AppComponent]
   bootstrap:[AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

This is how my feature module looks like

**SiteModule**

**site.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'sites', component: SiteListComponent }
]
export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**site.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [routing, SharedModule], 
   declarations: [SiteListComponent, EditCustomerComponent]
})
export class SiteModule{}
```

**CustomerModule**

**customer.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CustomerListComponent}
]
export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**customer.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [routing, SharedModule], 
   declarations: [CustomerListComponent, EditCustomerComponent]
})
export default class CustomerModule{}
```

The `SiteModule` and `CustomerModule` both have `EditCustomerComponent` in `declaration` list, when I navigate to `customers` `route`, I got multiple `declaration` `error` for `EditCustomerComponent` in both `SiteModule` and `CustomerModule`.

I know this can be fix by moving the `EditCustomerComponent` to shared `module` but that is not what I want since this `component` make more sense to resides in `customer module`.

Another workaround would be to export the `EditCustomerComponent` from `CustomerModule` and then import into `SiteModule` but that require the `CustomerModule` not to be `lazy loaded` which again I don't want.

I'm wondering if there is any other good way to handle this.

Comment: I don't understand why does the EditCustomerComponent logically reside in CustomerModule, but should exist in both CustomerModule and SiteModule? If it exists in both then it doesn't logically reside in one of them

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali Let me clear, `EditCustomerComponent` reside in `CustomerModule`. But this component need to be use as a directive in`SiteModule` as well.

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `Error: Error: Type EditCustomerComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: CustomerModule and SiteModule!(…)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A directive (and component) can only be listed in declarations of one module.

You need to move `EditCustomerComponent` to it's own `NgModule` (or just any another one with shared directives) and then add it to `imports: []` of `CustomerModule` and SiteModule`

Comment: I was wondering if there is a better way to tackle this, since I really want to keep my `EditCustomerComponent` in `Customer Module`. And don't want to put into it's own or `shared module`.

Comment: You can import `CustomerModule` in `SiteModule` and treat `CustomerModule` like a shared module.

Comment: Agree, but at the same time I want my `CustomerModule` to be lazy loaded. There is just one of it's `component` needed to be reuse in other modules of the application.

Comment: There is no other trick or something. A component just can be in only one module. It's your call what disadvantages you are more comfortable with.

Comment: I was not looking for a work around just to full fill my need. I just wanted to see if there is any other option available. But as you confirmed there is no other trick, I may just need to revise my application design and move this `component` to shared or in it's own module. Thanks so much for your time.